# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Template as array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Having a bit of an issue with Codeigniter - I am trying to build a module for a CMS system, but I get the following issue:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Template as array in (baseURL) on line 16

The code is as followed:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Forum extends CI_Controller {

    function Forum()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->template['module']   = 'forum';
        $this->load->model('forum_model', 'forum');
        $this->load->model('topic_model', 'topic');
        $this->load->model('message_model', 'message');
        $this->load->library("bbcode");
        $this->forum->get_user_level();

        $this->plugin->add_action('header', array(&$this, '_write_header'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 16? And why you have a & before the $this?

Comment: My apologies, line 16 is " $this->template['module']   = 'forum'; "

Comment: My guess is that `$this->template` is an object, which cannot be used as an array... But seriously, what do you not understand about the error message?

Comment: The "&$this" might be a typo, but I worked on this with a friend of mine, so I will confirm this.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - It's not what I don't understand, I am fairly new to the codeigniter framework, so not fully understanding why it's not working. I could do with someone perhaps pointing out where I am going wrong. Sorry to be a nuisance!

Comment: @katos You are not a nuisance. It is just that the error has nothing to do with CodeIgniter. It has to do with the fact that you are trying to use an object as an array, which you cannot do in PHP (with the exception of ArrayObject objects). You should try to figure out what `$this->template` is, and how you can set its values.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a library named 'template' that is auto-loaded.

Libraries are objects, and you're trying to use this one as an array, which is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: Simply stating what the problem is does not answer the question.

Comment: There is no question.